# How Can I get the border Side color in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I am designing a simple screen. I want to acheive this

[image]

How can I remove the topLeft border. I try to using border side to show only one side border but it showing error not able to change the another then uniform. Did i remove the app bar then stack the widget. Kindly tell me which thing I am doing wrong.
My Code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SendScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey =
        new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
        child: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
              onPressed: () {
                _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
              }),
          actions: [
            Container(
              width: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
                image: const DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  // width: 8,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            )
          ],
          shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              // bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(80),
            ),
          ),
          title: Text('Sliver AppBar'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.red[500],
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(80),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by top left border exactly. You mean add a border radius to top left too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a known "issue"](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12583). The problem is that once you assign a border radius, you don't know where the border starts and where it ends. Therefore flutter can't assign a border color to only certain border.

The only trick which works for you situation of everything I tried is to stack 2 container, the one on the back acting to do the border.

Here is the implementation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SendScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SendScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
        child: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
              onPressed: () {
                _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
              }),
          actions: [
            Container(
              width: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
                image: const DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  // width: 8,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            )
          ],
          shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              // bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(80),
            ),
          ),
          title: Text('Sliver AppBar'),
        ),
      ),
      body: CustomRectangle(
        borderSize: 20,
        borderColor: Colors.grey[300],
        height: 80.0,
        borderRadius: 80.0,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomRectangle extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double height;
  final double borderSize;
  final double borderRadius;
  final Color borderColor;

  const CustomRectangle({
    Key key,
    @required this.height,
    @required this.borderSize,
    @required this.borderRadius,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.borderColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(borderRadius)),
          child: Container(
            height: height + borderSize,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: borderColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(borderRadius)),
          child: Container(
            height: height,
            child: child,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Look at `CustomRectangle` it is my custom widget which solve your problem. You can expand from there.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Sorry for late response.